# How can I get the file name of a file that has been uploaded in a form, but the form itself was not submitted yet?

Tags: html, asp.net-core

So, I have this form where you can upload an image file. Before you upload a file there is a label saying 'Choose file", however I want to use JS, so when you upload a file with a file name let's say 'testImage.jpg' the label to change from 'Choose file' to 'testImage.jpg'.

However, I am not sure how in ASP.NET core I can get the file name of the uploaded file before the form is submitted.

An oversimplified version of the form

```
@model AddCardFormModel

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" asp-for="ImageFile" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" placeholder="">
          <label asp-for="ImageFile" class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
          <span asp-validation-for="ImageFile" class="small text-danger"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The file is not uploaded until you submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that with JS you can get the file from the input and change the content of the label.

Adding onchange-"changeLabelTextContent(this); to the `input` element and the code below do the magic perfectly.

```
function changeLabelTextContent(myFile){
        var file = myFile.files[0];
        
        var fileLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-file-label');

        fileLabel[0].textContent = file.name;
    }
```